# passport.js auth0 strategy Cross rigin request error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook, auth0

I am trying to use auth0 for social validation in my web app

i configured the app like this

```
auth0 : {
  domain : "mydomain",
  clientID : "myid",
  clientSecret: "mysecret",
  callbackURL: "/callback"
},
```

I request login from angular controller using http get to node backend like

```
  app.get('/auth/:connection', function(req, res, next) {

    passport.authenticate('auth0', {connection: req.params.connection}, function(err, user, info) {

    }) (req, res, next);
  });
```

I will call like auth/facebook for facebook login from angular client side controller.

The callback route is configured like this

```
app.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('auth0', { failureRedirect: '#!/authServiceImpl/login' }), 
    function(req, res) {
      console.log('auth0 callback');
      console.log(req.user);
    }
  );
```

Every time I am getting Cross origin request error. 
What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

> I request login from angular controller using http get to node backend like

You cannot perform OAuth over XHR. Instead of doing `$http.get('/auth/whatever')` you'd need to do `window.location.pathname = '/auth/whatever'` or `window.open('/auth/whatever')`